# Automated checking the sender and editing the sender on a .EML file in a specific directory

Tags: powershell, email, relay

Hi I'm faced with a challenge to avoid some slow moving and unresponsive bureaucracy. I'm trying to come up with a PowerShell I can use to check a directory for .eml files and check the sender for a specific domain and then if said domain exists change the domain to another domain. I'd like to mention that the .eml file names always change but I'd like the script to work no matter the filename as long as the extension is .eml

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried **yourself**. Explain what didn't work, add error messages in full to the question as well so we can help you with your code attempt.

Comment: $filePath = 'C:\inetpub\mailroot1\Queue\email.EML'
$tempFilePath = "$env:TEMP\$($filePath | Split-Path -Leaf)"
$find = 'email@randomdomain.com'
$replace = 'email@randomdomain.org'

(Get-Content -Path $filePath) -replace $find, $replace | Add-Content -Path $tempFilePath

Remove-Item -Path $filePath
Move-Item -Path $tempFilePath -Destination $filePath

Comment: It works if I know the file name. Unfortunately the file name always changes. I need something that can find the file by file type and perform the edits.

Comment: Also, it works if I create the folders on a computer I was testing on. On the server the folders are set up in a way they ask for me to hit yes on a file operation dialog box to edit or move files into the directory. I think that's messing up my automation as well.